# Pulling a child Class attribute From a Parent Class Array of Objects

Tags: java, inheritance, static, parent-child

I've written 1 parent class with 2 attributes, and 2 child classes with an additional attribute each that extend the parent class. I have a Driverclass that is the user Interface. In the driver I have an array of different objects (from all 3 classes), and I can identify if that object is instanceOf a child class. I can identify and change the 2 attributes associated with the parent class. but cannot for the life of me do the same for the additional attribute.

I have tried simply calling a getAttribute() type method from inside the child class but it says that I'm calling it from a static field and won't let me call a static method. I don't understand this because I'm sure I've made nothing static in my code.
I've tried changing things in my child class to static so I can call things but then every time I make a new object of the child class it overwrite every single other child object I already had and every instance of it has the same value for the unique variable. I've tried looking through here and I'm lost.

```
public class BandDriver{
    public Band[] collective;
    //this is the top of my driver, where "Band" is the Parent Class.


    private void addJazz(){
        System.out.println("What is the new Jazz Band's Name?");
        String name1=scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("How many players are in the new Jazz Band?");
        int players1=scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How much does the Jazz Charge per show?");
        float coverCharge1=scan.nextFloat();
        scan.nextLine();

        collective[size++]=new JazzBand(name1, players1, coverCharge1);
    }
    //this is where I create a new 'JazzBand' which is a child Class that 
    //extends 'Band'. the additional Attribute is "coverCharge".



    private void update(int bandIndex){
        System.out.println("\nBand Name: "+collective[bandIndex].name);
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to change the name of the band? (Y/N)");
        int decision=handleResponse(scan.nextLine());

        if (decision==6){
            System.out.println("\nEnter the new name for the Band");
            collective[bandIndex].name=scan.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("\nNumber of players: "+collective[bandIndex].numPlayers);
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to change the number of players " 
        +"in the band? (Y/N)");
        decision=handleResponse(scan.nextLine());

        if (decision==6){
            System.out.println("\nEnter the new number of players");
            collective[bandIndex].numPlayers=scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
        }

        if (collective[bandIndex] instanceof JazzBand){
            NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

            System.out.println("\nThe cover charge this band set is: " 
            +fmt.format(JazzBand.getCoverCharge()));
        }
    }

    //the getCoverCharge() Method is inside the JazzBand Child Class
```

1. I just want to return the value of the variable covercharge in the array 
   of objects the same way I have for the "name" and the "numPlayers" 
   variables.
2. the 'collective' Array is set up as a Band array and so I understand 
   that getCoverCharge is not a method for that class (that's the parent 
   class).
3. It keeps telling me I can't call on getCoverCharge because I'm trying to 
   make a static reference but nothing looks static to me.

Sorry this is so long... trying to be thorough.

Comment: when you call `JazzBand.getCoverCharge()`... you are attempting to access a static method on the JazzBand class.... you need an instance of JazzBand in order to call `getCoverCharge()`

Comment: `collective[bandIndex].getCoverCharge()`

Comment: yeah so that line only runs if the object in the position collective[bandIndex], is a jazz band. the method getCoverCharge() in NON static. but it says I'm trying to access it from a static field. Someone suggested writing a new method, and casting between parent and child Objects.

Comment: Well it is static.....`JazzBand.getCoverCharge()`... JazzBand here is the class...and you are calling `getCoverCharge()` on the class...so it is a static method